# How to get current user in a models of Pylons?

Tags: sqlalchemy, pylons

I have model like this:

```py
class CreatedMixin(DeclarativeBase):
    __abstract__ = True

    @declared_attr
    def updated_by(cls):
        return Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.user_id',
                      onupdate="cascade", ondelete="restrict"),
                      onupdate=CURRENT_USER_ID)

    updated_at = Column(DateTime, nullable=False, default=dt.now(),
                        onupdate=dt.now())
```

And auth with repoze.what-quickstart. How to get CURRENT_USER_ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do the following

```
identity = request.environ.get('repoze.who.identity')
```

and the gettin the user id

```
 id = identity['user'].id
```

Comment: When I import in module "from pylons import request" and use "identity = request.environ.get('repoze.who.identity')". I've got the following error "TypeError: No object (name: request) has been registered for this thread"

Comment: That's weird, it does work for me. Are you importing the request module on your model __init__.py?

Comment: I import request in my models __init__.py. And write "identity = request.environ.get('repoze.who.identity')". But whatever got the eror: TypeError: No object (name: request) has been registered for this thread

Comment: Mmhh..well in that case maybe you should try to expose your model function definition to one of your controller functions and pass the userid as an argument

Comment: tnx, it works. Before that I tried to use mixin. I understand that it does not work with mixin.